# Inserting lists into List Object to view in dataGrid

Tags: c#, arrays, json, list, datagrid

I have wrote a code which reads url, parsing the json and stores the data in list.

Now i made 4 new lists:

```
List<int> list_AmountNeed = new List<int>();
List<int> list_TotalCost = new List<int>();
List<int> list_TotalLose = new List<int>();
List<int> list_TotalGain = new List<int>();
```

and using a while loop:

```
while (z < list_Exp.Count)

{

list_AmountNeed.Add((goalexp - currentexp) / Convert.ToInt32(list_Exp[z]));
list_TotalLose.Add(list_AmountNeed[z] * (list_Amount_MadeFrom_One[z] * list_BuyPrice_MadeFrom_One[z] + list_Amount_MadeFrom_Two[z] * list_BuyPrice_MadeFrom_Two[z]));
list_TotalGain.Add(list_AmountNeed[z] * list_AmountMade[z] * list_SellPrice[z]);
list_TotalCost.Add(list_TotalGain[z] - list_TotalLose[z]);

z++;

}
```

Eventually, I get these 4 lists where each one of them is made of 24 "cells". For example:

```
list_TotalCost[0]=1,list_TotalCost[1]=2,list_TotalCost[3]=3...list_TotalCost[24]=5
```

Now, I have made a datagrid using blend for visual studio 2015.
I want this 4 lists to be columns at the data grid.

How can i insert them into a datagrid that will show 3 columns with 24 cells each?

Thank You.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need to map those 3 lists into a single object `MyDataObject`, correct?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to separate your csv rows into 3 lists. You can already assign each row as an object `MyDataObject`:

```
List<MyDataObject> myRows = new List<MyDataObject>();
while (!reader1.EndOfStream)
{
    var line = reader1.ReadLine();
    var values = line.Split(',');

    MyDataObject row = new MyDataObject() { 
        id = Convert.ToDouble(values[0]),
        name = values[1],
        amount = Convert.ToInt32(values[2])
    };

    myRows.Add(row);
}
```

One thing though: make sure your object property data types should match your values,

**i.e:** `MyDataObject.id` should be double since `id = Convert.ToDouble(values[0])`, etc.

Comment: i updated the question mate, probably didnt explain my self correct. the rows are more like items calculated in a while loop, not a value from the csv file.

Comment: how about setting `MyDataObject row` properties after the calculation? You can use something like `MyDataObject row = new MyDataObject() { id = CALCULATED_VAL, name = ..... } `